# No errors, but react component does not render

Tags: reactjs

I'm new here and I have a rather annoying problem. I am serving a react app from a go server, everything seems to be working fine (bundle.js is being generated where its supposed to, server is rendering the correct page, no errors) yet no matter what I do the component will not render. To be honest I have probably just been staring at code for too long.

The code is here https://github.com/sambragge/doulaspotPublic

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to help me, hopefully I am just missing something stupidly simple.

Answer (score 0):

You're not serving the `bundle.js` file.

Change the `func` in `router.go` to:

```
func (rtr *Router) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.URL.Path {
        case "/":
            http.ServeFile(w, r, "./view/index.html")
            return
        case "/bundle.js":
            http.ServeFile(w, r, "./view/bundle.js")
            return
    }
}
```